# Deskewing a license plate image after detecting region using cascade classifier

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

After detecting the license plate region using cascade classifier and finding the skew angle, I am having a hard time trying to find the minimum rectangle. I have searched the internet for available resources on the topic  but none of those would suffice, except for this one[this one](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-rotation-deskewing/). In that blog post there is a method void deskew(const char* filename, double angle), and there is a line

```
 cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator it = img.begin<uchar>();
cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator end = img.end<uchar>();
  for (; it != end; ++it)
    if (*it)
  points.push_back(it.pos());
```

, which is where am having a hard time to find emgu cv equivalent for it. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: which line exactly do you mean?

Comment: All of those lines, I know points is a VectorOfPoints in Emgu cv, but how do we find the beginning and end for the Matrix?